# Angular4 - ngIf else with tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, ngx-bootstrap

I have a dialog with different tabs. I want to use the tabs for users as well for group of users. The dialog is quite similar therefore I want to use it as a generic one.... Tabs are used from `ngx-bootstrap` (1.6.6)

```
<tabset> 
    <div *ngIf="isUserEditor; else groupDetails">
        <tab heading="User details">
                Details...content 4 user
         </tab>
    </div>  
    <ng-template #groupDetails>
        <tab heading="Group details">
                Group content
         </tab>
    </ng-template>
    <tab heading="Permissions">
                Permission settings 
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I'm facing different problems:

1. The above syntax for the if/else does not work. i.e. the content of `UserDetails` is displayed independent of the selected tab.

   a) Why is the content of `UserDetails` displayed in all tabs?

   b)  If I change to if/then/else-Syntax `UserDetails` is not displayed in all tabs, but the tab-heading remains.
2. The display order is annoying - namely I see the permission tab at the first position - but I want to have it on the last position. Is there a way to achieve it? *Note:* The `UserDetails` might  be split up into more than one tab, the `Permission` tab might be not the last tab which will be added. I'm looking for a solution without too much code duplication.
3. Is there a diff if I use for the `*ngIf` a `div` container or a `ng-container`?

Honestly I have no clue if this is bug in `ngx-bootstrap` or not... But it could be as well incorrect usage of syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
  <tabset *ngIf="isUserEditor>=0">
     <div *ngIf="isUserEditor; then userDetails else groupDetails"></div>
     <ng-template #userDetails>
        <tab heading="User details">
            Details...content 4 user
        </tab>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-template #groupDetails>
        <tab heading="Group details">
            Group content
        </tab>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-container *ngIf="true">
        <tab heading="Permissions">
            Permission settings 
        </tab>
     </ng-container>
  </tabset>
```

The main trick consists of 2 parts:

1. `isUserEditor` needs to be initialized to `-1` and so the tabs are not rendered at the very beginning!
2. If I place the last tab as well into a container ==> calculation if displayed or not are done at the very ending => order remains correct!

Comment: I had a similar situation with an ngIf causing the tabs to change order. Adding `*ngIf="true"` to the other tabs (no need for `<ng-container>`) keeps the order.

Answer (score 0):

1/3. For your first problem is because you are wrapping `<tab>` inside `<div>`. You dont need to handle visibility like that. There is a `[active]` input for `<tab>`:

```
<tabset>
    <tab header="User details" [active]="tabsActivity.tab1" (select)="tabToggle('tab1')">
        Details...content 4 user
    </tab>

    <tab header="Group details" [active]="tabsActivity.tab2" (select)="tabToggle('tab2')">
        Group content
    </tab>

    <tab header="Permissions" [active]="tabsActivity.tab3" (select)="tabToggle('tab3')">
        Permission settings
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Where tabsActivity is a model for all states of tabs.
`(select)` will toggle individual activity of tabs by chaning boolean state of `tabsActivity` properties.

2. Problem with order will be resolved when you use `[active]`.

Comment: thx for your response although it did NOT really hit the point. Reg. your first comment: that's the correct Agnular4 syntax - sorry, pal. And the second point: `[active]` is really a nice feature - but... anyway thx for trying.

Comment: Ah ok. I didnt mine tabs without `div` wrapper, but no problem :)